# gcloud sql instances patch fails with invalid data error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

When trying to add high availability on an existing Cloud SQL instance using:

`gcloud sql instances patch $INSTANCE --project $PROJECT --availability-type regional`

the process fails with this message

`The following message will be used for the patch API method.
{"project": "$PROJECT", "name": "$INSTANCE", "settings": {"availabilityType": "REGIONAL", "databaseFlags": [{"name": "sql_mode", "value": "TRADITIONAL"}, {"name": "default_time_zone", "value": "+01:00"}]}}
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 400: The incoming request contained invalid data.`

It also fails using the web interface.
Gcloud version `Google Cloud SDK [280.0.0]`
This is the output of the log (not much help that I can see):

```
2020-02-14 11:01:34,476 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: [u'gcloud', u'sql', u'instances']
2020-02-14 11:01:34,510 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: [u'gcloud', u'sql', u'instances', u'patch']
2020-02-14 11:01:34,517 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.sql.instances.patch] with arguments: [--availability-type: "regional", --project: "$PROJECT", INSTANCE: "$INSTANCE"]
2020-02-14 11:01:35,388 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ The following message will be used for the patch API method.

2020-02-14 11:01:35,398 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ {"project": "$PROJECT", "name": "$INSTANCE", "settings": {"availabilityType": "REGIONAL", "databaseFlags": [{"name": "sql_mode", "value": "TRADITIONAL"}, {"name": "default_time_zone", "value": "+01:00"}]}}

2020-02-14 11:01:35,865 DEBUG    root            (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 400: The incoming request contained invalid data.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 981, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\sql\instances\patch.py", line 306, in Run
    return RunBasePatchCommand(args, self.ReleaseTrack())
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\sql\instances\patch.py", line 278, in RunBasePatchCommand
    instance=instance_ref.instance))
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\third_party\apis\sql\v1beta4\sql_v1beta4_client.py", line 697, in Patch
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\lib\third_party\apitools\base\py\base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\lib\third_party\apitools\base\py\base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "C:\Users\udAL\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\lib\third_party\apitools\base\py\base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/$PROJECT/instances/$INSTANCE?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '400', 'content-length': '269', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Fri, 14 Feb 2020 10:01:35 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The incoming request contained invalid data.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The incoming request contained invalid data.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidRequest"
      }
    ]
  }
}
>
2020-02-14 11:01:35,868 ERROR    root            (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 400: The incoming request contained invalid data.
2020-02-14 11:01:35,898 DEBUG    root            Metrics reporting process started...
```

**Edit:**

When using the gcloud cli command:

gcloud patch with 3 input parameters

1. Both $PROJECT and $INSTANCE do exist since I can `gcloud sql databases list --instance $INSTANCE --project $PROJECT` and it works fine.
2. availability-type=regional it's documented so should work

I'm not constructing the request manually, I'm using gcloud CLI

When using the console.cloud.google.com web interface:

Main menu -> SQL -> *select instance* -> Enable High Availability.
It's a button, no parameters added by myself.

Both return the same error "The incoming request contained invalid data." 
Can't see how I may be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your data in the incoming request.

I used the [Method: instances.patch](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/patch) and it worked as expected for me.

`project`
`instance-name`

`request body`:

```
  "settings": {
    "availabilityType": "REGIONAL",
    "databaseFlags": [
      {
        "name": "sql_mode",
        "value": "TRADITIONAL"
      },
      {
        "name": "default_time_zone",
        "value": "+01:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Curl command:

````
  'https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/your-project/instances/your_instancet?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"settings":{"availabilityType":"REGIONAL","databaseFlags":[{"name":"sql_mode","value":"TRADITIONAL"},{"name":"default_time_zone","value":"+01:00"}]}}' \
  --compressed```
````

Response 200:

```
{
  "kind": "sql#operation",
  "targetLink": "https://content-sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/your-project/instances/your-instance",
  "status": "PENDING",
  "user": "@cloud.com",
  "insertTime": "2020-02-14T12:35:37.615Z",
  "operationType": "UPDATE",
  "name": "3f55c1be-97b5-4d37-8d1f-15cb61b4c6cc",
  "targetId": "your-instance",
  "selfLink": "https://content-sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/wave25-vladoi/operations/3f55c1be-97b5-4d37-8d1f-15cb61b4c6cc",
  "targetProject": "your-project"
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean...
Please see edit for clarification

Comment: I am asking to try the operation using the API, and tell me if is working

Comment: I'm not used at all to the API. I'll try to set it up but I'm hoping to be able to do it on the cli.

Comment: just follow my answer, add the project name, instance-name, and the fields on the request body that I posted. Just go to the link I posted and look for Try this API

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't know about that.
Exactly the same error

Comment: can you try to create a new sql instance and test your patch command on it. Let's see if works on other instance. I tested on my sql instance and it worked just fine.

Comment: With a new default instance it works, but with a cloned one it doesn't.
I've been trying to locate which is the parameter/s that prevents me from activating the HA but haven't found it yet. It's pretty frustrating

Comment: Could you please try to update to the [latest version 281.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#28100_2020-02-18) in the gcloud SDK? And then try again? just to discard possibilities?

Comment: Same error: HTTPError 400: The incoming request contained invalid data.

Comment: Could it be related to use lowercase letter `regional` instead of capital `REGIONAL`? Could you please try again with: `gcloud sql instances patch $INSTANCE --project $PROJECT --availability-type REGIONAL`?
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha) the command is shown with Capital, and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/patch#--availability-type) is shown with lowercase. It works for me with both: lowercase and Capital

Comment: Are your var set ritght? `$INSTANCE` `$PROJECT`? If you echo them, are the values ok?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's none of that, I've tried. It doesn't work even when doing so through console.cloud.google.com (same error), through the web interface it can't be because of a wrong parameter. It's something specific in the configuration of this Cloud SQL instance but nothing points to what exactly and couldn't figure it out by myself.